# Is there a way to dump a Mongo database as a static JSON file?

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm having a heckuva time writing tests using Angular. It's much easier for me to test my functions "manually" using live data. Therefore I would like a copy of all my data from which I can reference to make sure my functions are working correctly.

Comment: You can get mongodb data in plain human readable json format. But this is limited to collection level. I mean, you have to run the command for each collection separately. The command is, mongoexport.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a shot.